# What can't I make this nav display inline?

Tags: css, html

I am trying to display the navigation menu show below as inline. However any other changes it gets applied but not the display:inline-block; property.

```
<div class="container">
    <a class="hide" href="#">Close</a>
     <header>
         <div class="title">
             <h1>I'M JAMIE</h1>
              <h4>Looking for a development opportunity and much more</h4>
         </div>
     <nav>
             <ul>
         <li><a href="#">About me </a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">About me </a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
         </ul>
             </nav>
    </header>
```

the css code is

```
 header nav ul li a {
   display:inline-block;

 }
```

Comment: Just display the `li` element inline not the a.

Comment: Or remove the `ul` and `li` altogether.

Comment: @GolezTrol yes, but an unordered list allows you to give it more style. Make it look like a menu bar and so. However the nav element should give you that possibility too. Not decided here :-)

Comment: @mouser True. The list does allow more styling (also having the extra elements around the links themselves). Removing them is just an alternative to your fine answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/33mt8xff/

```
header > nav > ul > li {
   display:inline-block;

 }
```

This will display the list items next to each other.
The `>` means select the children. Now only li elements that are descendants of the header element get styled.

Answer (score 0):

```
header > nav > ul > li {
   float: left;
   margin-right: 10px;
   list-style: none;
}
```

or

```
header > nav > ul > li {
   display: inline-block;
}
```